# Apache Camel onException Custom Error Handler is not working

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am new to apache camel features. So I have a problem with the **DefaultErrorHandler** in our project.

There are some errors in which we are not using any custom error handler. Whenever an exception occurs, apache camel logs it and this log level is **ERROR**.
Apache camel is handling failure through DefaultErrorHandler which propagates exceptions back to the caller since there isn’t any custom error handler.

This errors are like "User not found" so this shouldn't be a **ERROR**, this can be a **WARN** or **INFO**. Since we are not handling it, DefaultErrorHandler by Apache Camel handles it.

The error log like this on the server:

```
 main 2022-08-05 15:24:43.537 ERROR [user-manager] 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.c.p.e.DefaultErrorHandler            : Failed delivery for (MessageId:-0000000 on Exc │    │
│ main +[                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      │    │
│ main +[ Message History (complete message history is disabled)                                                                                                                                                                               │    │
│ main +[ ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                              │    │
│ main +[ RouteId              ProcessorId          Processor                                                                        Elapsed (ms)                                                                                              │    │
│ main +[ [PostUserToIdentity] [PostUserToIdentity] [from[direct://business.postUserToIdentity]                                    ] [        27]                                                                                              │    │
│ main +[     ...                                                                                                                                                                                                                              │    │
│ main +[ [PostUserToIdentity] [to58              ] [direct:postUserToIdentityRequestedInternal                                    ] [         0]                                                                                              │    │
│ main +[                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      │    │
│ main +[ Stacktrace                                                                                                                                                                                                                           │    │
│ main +[ ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                              │    │
│ main +[                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      │    │
│ main                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         │    │
│ main com.user.manager.exception.ConflictException: User already exists
```

So, I wrote a Custom Handler and a RouteClass which extends the **RouteBuilder** with the proper Camel **OnException** clause.

**OnConflictExceptionRoute Class**

```
@Component
public class OnConflictExceptionRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() {
        log.info("Configuring extended create user by context route");

        onException(ConflictException.class)
            .process(new ConflictExceptionHandler())
            .handled(true);

        from("direct:business.postUserToIdentity")
            .routeId("PostUserToIdentity")
            .onException(ConflictException.class)
            .process(new ConflictExceptionHandler());
    }
}
```

**Custom Error Handler**

```
@Slf4j
public class ConflictExceptionHandler implements Processor {

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) {
        log.info("USER ALREADY EXISTS!");
        throw new ConflictException().withMessage("USER ALREADY EXISTS!");
    }
}
```

At the application startup, I could see that the Configure method in the RouteClass is triggered.

But when I am triggering the flow, I am still seeing the same error is handling by the DefaultErrorHandler.

Why it is not working? Is there any missing configuration? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a deep analysis, I found that I'd to resolve this issue with the service that we called in the application by extending the RouteBuilder class like this.

```
  @Override
    protected ErrorHandlerFactory createErrorHandlerBuilder() {
        DefaultErrorHandlerBuilder errorHandlerBuilder = super.defaultErrorHandler();
        // Changed from ERROR because it is expected that the service handles the exception.
        errorHandlerBuilder.setLevel(LoggingLevel.INFO.toString());
        RedeliveryPolicyDefinition policy = new RedeliveryPolicyDefinition();
        policy.setDisableRedelivery("false");
        policy.setRetriesExhaustedLogLevel(getRetriesExhaustedLogLevel().toString());
        errorHandlerBuilder.setRedeliveryPolicy(policy);
        return errorHandlerBuilder;
    }
```

Note : ExhaustedLogLevel is setted as **DEBUG**.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have      .handled(true)
in your

```
onException(ConflictException.class)
.handled(true) // before any process
```

Answer (score 0):

Camel has different exception handling behaviors. Route based: its handles for just this route in your example direct:business.postUserToIdentity route has a  one route based exception handler and its overrides others .  another one RouteBuilder based exception handler . its handles all routes in a routebuilder class. you have two definition.  they have same  onException . it is not logical . you can change like that your code .

```
 onException(ConflictException.class)
                .process(new ConflictExceptionHandler())
                .handled(true)
                .log("Exception handler works ${exception}");

        from("direct:business.postUserToIdentity")
                .routeId("PostUserToIdentity")
                .log("started")
                .throwException(new ConflictException());
```

Comment: Hey Eray, thanks for recommending the changes. I was aware that the code logically incorrect, right now I applied the changes and triggered the flow again. It's still same.. Do you think that any configuration is missing? There isn't any log about exception handler as well.

Comment: By the way, at first the routeId was "PostUserToIdentityRoute" not "PostUserToIdentity". 

Now I changed the routeId to the "PostUserToIdentity" and I am getting an error related to multiple consumers..

Caused by: org.apache.camel.FailedToStartRouteException: Failed to start route PostUserToIdentityRoute because of Multiple consumers for the same endpoint is not allowed: direct://business.postUserToIdentity

Comment: I think you have multiple from("direct:business.postUserToIdentity") in camel context can u check out it

Comment: Thank Eray, I think we are keeping this camel context file in the cluster, I have to ask to the DevOps guys. But in the mean time, is there anyway to handle this ConflictException for all routes without specifying any route? According to the camel, it can be.
(USING A PROCESSOR AS A FAILURE HANDLER)
https://camel.apache.org/manual/exception-clause.html

I tried it and it didn't work.

Comment: for global exception handling like spring boot @ExceptionHandler  check out here https://camel.apache.org/manual/route-configuration.html you are welcome

Comment: Can't use RouteConfigurationBuilder, seems like doesn't exist in 3.6.0, I'll double check it. There must be a way to specify error handler for all routes for a specific exception class.. But I guess the issue is different, I can see that extending RouteBuilder is working since I can see the log but couldn't see any log from onException/process..